# remove white border footer

Tags: html, css, footer

How can I remove the white border on bottom of the browser (google chrome)?

[image: white border of bottom footer]

This is the code I have used:

```
footer {
  color: white;
  width: 101%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  background-color: #343434;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: 101.5%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
}

footer > div {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <!--main things-->
</main>

<footer>
    <div>
        <p>FastCycle werdt gecreëerd door HP-programming vzw. Copyright &copy; 2015</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I have try to place the `margin-button` to set on zero but it didn't help. Also I have place the `margin-left` to -16px and `width` to 101.5%? Why?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I think the border you refer to is the one from body. Did you use css reset e.g. `body { margin: 0; }` ?

Comment: maybe is the `margin-top: -8px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the following to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
```

or alternatively, create a new CSS class:

```
body { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

If that doesn't work, in Chrome, if you press F12, it will bring up a panel that allows you to view the styles of elements. Hover over the elements until you find the one that's creating the whitespace, and remove the padding/margin from it.

Comment: A suggestion is to avoid inline style.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to your css

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

And some cleaning for your css footer

```
footer {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #343434;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom:0;
}

footer > div {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="footer">
  <div id="inner">
   FastCycle werdt gecreerd door HP-programming vzw. Copyright &copy; 2015
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Use this CSS:

```
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#footer {
 background-color: #343434;
 color: #ffffff;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

#inner {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px -500px;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0px;
 width: 1000px;
}
```

Also, you've set the Width and the Left Margin twice with 2 different values so you might want to clean that up. Regardless my code gives the same result except without the white space. Feel free to add back some of the stuff I've taken out if other elements depend on it.

Comment: For `<div id="footer">...</div>` is a tag for it. Why should you use a `div`?

Comment: No particular reason. Just habit. That's the way to do it in HTML4.01 which was the standard when I learnt. Of course if you're using HTML5 <footer>...</footer> is fine.